# Is it possible to publish a dacpac file using Microsoft.Sqlserver.Management.Smo?

Tags: .net, sql-server, smo, dacpac

I've looked around but am unable to find anything. I do not have access to

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac
```

, unfortunately, and am unable to download it onto the machine I'm working on due to permissions.

**EDIT** Should also mention I'm running VS 2012 with SP4 and SQL Server 2008. My installation of VS has SSDT installed, but for some reason the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac DLL was not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish a DacPac using SMO with powershell, below is a copy of the example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/deploy-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017#deploy-a-dac-using-powershell).

```
## Set a SMO Server object to the default instance on the local computer.  
CD SQLSERVER:\SQL\localhost\DEFAULT  
$srv = get-item .  

## Open a Common.ServerConnection to the same instance.  
$serverconnection = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection($srv.ConnectionContext.SqlConnectionObject)  
$serverconnection.Connect()  
$dacstore = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacStore($serverconnection)  

## Load the DAC package file.  
$dacpacPath = "C:\MyDACs\MyApplication.dacpac"  
$fileStream = [System.IO.File]::Open($dacpacPath,[System.IO.FileMode]::OpenOrCreate)  
$dacType = [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacType]::Load($fileStream)  

## Subscribe to the DAC deployment events.  
$dacstore.add_DacActionStarted({Write-Host `n`nStarting at $(get-date) :: $_.Description})  
$dacstore.add_DacActionFinished({Write-Host Completed at $(get-date) :: $_.Description})  

## Deploy the DAC and create the database.  
$dacName  = "MyApplication"  
$evaluateTSPolicy = $true  
$deployProperties = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DatabaseDeploymentProperties($serverconnection,$dacName)  
$dacstore.Install($dacType, $deployProperties, $evaluateTSPolicy)  
$fileStream.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the dll's on if you can't run an installer (or can you not even do that?

You can also run the deploy from another machine, either by generating a deployment script against the database or an offline backup of it.

Ed

Comment: I can't even do that. It's a government machine->locked down. All the machines on the network are similarly set up. I take it from your answer that SMO can't handle this? Right now I've got a .bat file taking care of things, so I am able to get it done. I just wanted to get it all into the code base, if possible.

Comment: You should open 2 VS instances, open a SQL project in 1 and attach from the other to view modules. You'll see where it loads DacFx from. It'll either be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin (assuming only VS2012 was installed, with no separate SSDT update installed) or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Dac\120" (assuming you installed the SQL Server 2014 compatible SSDT update, which moves Dacfx to a local location to avoid conflicts.